# Multithreading- Open url from Dataframe using selenium and scrape using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, selenium, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code to verify a piece of text from the scraped information using the below code. However, I don't know how to do a multithreaded execution. I really appreciate any suggestion to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
        'referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
        }
data = {'RefNo':  [2001, 2002,2003,2004],
        'link': ['https://www.google.com/search?&q=Python', 'https://www.google.com/search?&q=Java','https://www.google.com/search?&q=Visual%20Basic','https://www.google.com/search?&q=c']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['RefNo','link'])

for index, row in df.iloc[0:].iterrows():
    dr = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/synup/Desktop/Python/chromedriver")
    dr.get(row['link'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dr.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for content in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"data-attrid":"subtitle"}):
        if (content.text=='Programming language'):
            print(row['RefNo'],row['link'])
    dr.quit()
```

Comment: You can use concurrent.futures: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html.

Comment: Here is an example:`with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(function, parameters)
    print(future.result()) #prints the output
`

Comment: Thanks @Kral. I tried this but I don't know how to pass the 2 columns of dataframe.

Comment: You can try to pass them in as a tupe or list: `executor.submit(function, [df])`. I believe the submit function also allows multiple arguments like so: `submit(fn, /, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks it worked!